# alloy analyzer didn't execute my run command exactly

Tags: alloy

my code is this:

but when I execute this.it show me only one house and one mohre.
what should I do???

```
abstract one sig board{}
sig mohre {live:one  state }
sig house extends board{ver:one Int,hor:one Int,mo: mohre }
enum state{alive,dead}
run{#house>10 and #mohre>8}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `run` does not specify a *scope*. The default scope is 3 atoms of each `sig` and 16 integers ([-8..7]).

The US of cardinality 10 is therefore out if *scope*. Basically those models are in lala land. If you lower the cardinality or increase the scope things should work.

```
   run{#house>10 and #mohre>8} for 12 but 5 int
```

This command allows 12 atoms of all types and has 32 integers. Weirdly, the integers are specified by their *bit width* and 5 bits gives you 32 values.

Additionally, you put a constraint on the `abstract sig one board`. Remove the `one` since that prevents a solution with more than one house.